# Regular Expression for searching a string starting with string 1, does not containing string 2, and ends in string 3

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I'm currently writing a regular expression to search in files using visual studio regex pattern, the pattern im working on is something like this

1. starts with string 1
2. doesnt contain string2 in between strings 1 and 3
3. ends with string 3

Im modifying a previous regex that i used sometime ago (2 years?) but can't come up with something that fits the need. This is currently im trying to work on.

```
\bword1\W+(?:\w+\W+)*^((?!word2).)*$word3\b
```

Can anyone teach me a thing or two about regex?

Thank you

Comment: If string 3 contains within it string 2, is that allowed or not allowed?

Comment: Is regexp a must? Don't think regexp is required to achieve what you want.

Comment: For #2 do you mean between string 1 and **3**?

Comment: Try `string1(?:(?!string1|string2).)*string3` or `string1(?:(?!string2).)*string3`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as per my requirement, the real world string2 isnt contained in string 3, so to answer, not allowed.

Comment: @ChrisLam, yes string2 should not be contained in/ between strings 1 and 3, 

the reason regexp is required is we're going to search within files using Visual Studio find in files, and the files is around 10000 or more files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look:

- *starts with string 1* - **`string1`**
- *doesn't contain string2 in between strings 1 and 3* - here, you need to use  a [`.` tempered with a negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) - `(?:(?!string1|string2).)*?` (note that to match across line, in Visual Studio S&R you need to use `[\s\S\r]` instead of a `.` (`\r` is necessary here for the reason `[\s\S]` does not match a line break in VS S&R regex))
- *ends with string 3* - **`string3`**.

So, the whole expression is

```
string1(?:(?!string1|string2).)*?string3
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4G07g/1).